# Datatable not refreshing with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have two calendar controls and one command button. basically i want to give a range of date to pick the data from the database and then when i press the command button the datatable is displayed in the dialog box, the problem is java bean class is working it is loading the exact data which i want, but the datatable is not refreshing with command button click
my code is given;

```
<h:form id="form" >        
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.dateFrom}" id="calFrom" pattern="yyyy-mm-dd">  
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{calendarBean.handleDateSelectFrom}" />  
    </p:calendar>  
    <p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.dateTo}"  id="calTo" pattern="yyyy-mm-dd">  
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  listener="#{calendarBean.handleDateSelectTo}" />  
    </p:calendar>  
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{calendarBean.submit()}" update="fTable" onclick="aDlg.show()">
        <f:ajax render=":form:fTable" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:dialog id="aDialog" header="Filter List" widgetVar="aDlg"
                            modal="true" showEffect="explode"
                            hideEffect="explode" >                                      
    <p:panel id="pnl">
        <p:dataTable id="fTable" value="#{calenderBean.list}" var="row" >
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.ID}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.Name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Time">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.Time}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="User">
                <h:outputText value="#{row.userName}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        </p:panel>                  
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

kindly guide me regarding this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do, is remove the `f:ajax`, it's not working good with Primefaces. Also the `update` attribute should do everything.
This said, I have the very same code as yours which is working good.
If removing `f:ajax` is not working, try to check your managed bean scope (May be it's of request scope and data is re-initialized with every request)

Comment: I have removed the f:ajax, and my managed bean scope is sessionscope, but still having the same problem

Comment: Thanx @Laabidi i have solved the issue .. the problem was i havent write the setter and getter for the list from which the datatable is populated. anyhow thanx for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating the dialog instead.
    update="fTable"